# Can a restricted VECM be expressed as two ARDL equations?

Tags: time-series, model, vector-error-correction-model, ardl

I'm currently working on a model where I have two variables that are cointegrated. The issue is that, whilst they are cointegrated (based both on intuition and tests), the relationship is lag-heavy.

$x_t$ has a contemporaneous relationship with $y_t$, whilst $y_t$ has a relationship with the longer lags of $x_t$. Something like 12 periods back. The reason for this is that $y_t$ is construction, which takes around three years between the decision being made and completion.

I've landed on using two parallel ARDL models, which work and fit the intuition.

$x_t = f(y_t)$

$y_t = f(x_{t-12})$

Would an appropriately restricted VECM model be equivalent to this two-stage approach?

Comment: Hi: can you just forward lag $x_t$ by 12 and then use the standard vecm ? I'm not familar with the pros and cons of doing that but, intuitively, it seems like it would be okay.

Comment: This is sort of what I was thinking. My feeling is that it would be equivalent.

Comment: I guess the problem would be that there's uncertainty in the assumption that $y_t$ and $x_{t-12}$ are cointegrated. maybe do tests for cointegration from $i = 1,\ldots 12$ and see what is strongest.